# Linux: How do I archive select file extensions in an unknown tree

Tags: linux, tar, archive

What is the best way to archive select file extensions in an unknown tree.
I cannot use exclude options in tar/gzip/rsync as it would be impossible to exclude all possible extension variations.

Example to backup all .foo and .bar files in a recursive tree but not other unknown file types.

I presume this will need to be a combination of ls/find, grep and tar/gzip.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very similar to [dmourati's answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/272138/linux-how-do-i-archive-select-file-extensions-in-an-unknown-tree/272140#272140), but without xargs.

```
find /path/to/tree \( -name "*.foo" -o -name "*.bar" \) -print0 | tar -T /dev/stdin --null -cvzf foobar.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
find /path/to/tree \( -name "*.foo" -o -name "*.bar" \) -print0 | xargs -r0 tar cvzf foobar.tar.gz
```

You generate the list of files via the find command and then pipe that to xargs and on to tar.

Comment: This could cause issues if there are too many files for `xargs` to put in a single command.

Comment: There are a lot of them and the tree does get quite deep in places

Comment: Maybe just me but it seams to be ignoring the first file extension and just tar'ing the second.

Comment: Editted to fix the grouping